# upload file and read with file_get_contents php

Tags: php, mysql, xml, simplexml

i´m trying to upload a file using file_get_contents and read it, currently i can read the file and get data, but only with files inside the project folder, can someone tell me, how to do this with a post method or someting?

Here My code:

```html
   <?php

$RE_fecha='.*?((?:2|1)\d{3}(?:-|\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:-|\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))(?:T|\s)(?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]))';





$xmlCont=file_get_contents('archivo');
//$xmlCont=file_get_contents($_FILES);

$RE_receptor='<.*?Receptor.*?rfc="(.*?)"';
$RE_nombre='<.*?Receptor.*?nombre="(.*?)"';
$RE_calle='<.*?Receptor.*?calle="(.*?)"';
$RE_cp='<.*?Receptor.*?codigoPostal="(.*?)"';
$RE_colonia='<.*?Receptor.*?colonia="(.*?)"';
$RE_estado='<.*?Receptor.*?estado="(.*?)"';
$RE_municipio='<.*?Receptor.*?municipio="(.*?)"';
$RE_noExterior='<.*?Receptor.*?noExterior="(.*?)"';
$RE_noInterior='<.*?Receptor.*?noInterior="(.*?)"';
$RE_pais='<.*?Receptor.*?pais="(.*?)"';



//Extraer fecha del xml
preg_match_all("/".$RE_fecha."/is",$xmlCont, $matches);
$fechaxmlunix=strtotime($matches[1][0]);
$fechaxmlorig=$matches[1][0];
unset($matches);

//Extraer rfc del receptor
preg_match_all('/'.$RE_receptor.'/is',$xmlCont, $matches);
$rfc=$matches[1][0]; // RFC del receptor
unset($matches);

//Extraer rfc del receptor
preg_match_all('/'.$RE_nombre.'/is',$xmlCont, $matches);
$nombre_rs=$matches[1][0]; // RFC del receptor
unset($matches);

//Extraer rfc del receptor
preg_match_all('/'.$RE_calle.'/is',$xmlCont, $matches);
$calle=$matches[1][0]; // RFC del receptor
unset($matches);

//Extraer código postal del receptor
preg_match_all('/'.$RE_cp.'/is',$xmlCont, $matches);
$cp=$matches[1][0]; // RFC del receptor
unset($matches);

//Extraer colonia del receptor
preg_match_all('/'.$RE_colonia.'/is',$xmlCont, $matches);
$colonia=$matches[1][0]; // RFC del receptor
unset($matches);

//Extraer estado del receptor
preg_match_all('/'.$RE_estado.'/is',$xmlCont, $matches);
$estado=$matches[1][0]; // RFC del receptor
unset($matches);

//Extraer municipio del receptor
preg_match_all('/'.$RE_municipio.'/is',$xmlCont, $matches);
$municipio=$matches[1][0]; // RFC del receptor
unset($matches);

//Extraer no. exterior del receptor
preg_match_all('/'.$RE_noExterior.'/is',$xmlCont, $matches);
$no_exterior=$matches[1][0]; // RFC del receptor
unset($matches);

//Extraer no. interior del receptor
preg_match_all('/'.$RE_noInterior.'/is',$xmlCont, $matches);
$no_interior=$matches[1][0]; // RFC del receptor
unset($matches);

//Extraer pais del receptor
preg_match_all('/'.$RE_pais.'/is',$xmlCont, $matches);
$pais=$matches[1][0]; // RFC del receptor
unset($matches);

echo "Fecha es: ".$fechaxmlorig."<br />";
echo "Fecha UNIX es: ".$fechaxmlunix."<br />";
echo "RFC receptor es: ".$rfc."<br />";
echo "Nombre: ".$nombre_rs."<br />";
echo "Calle: ".$calle."<br />";
echo "No. Exterior: ".$no_exterior."<br />";
echo "No. Interior: ".$no_interior."<br />";
echo "Colonia: ".$colonia."<br />";
echo "Municipio: ".$municipio."<br />";
echo "Estado: ".$estado."<br />";
echo "País: ".$pais."<br />";
echo "Código Postal: ".$cp."<br />";


// open MySQL connection
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "rbp") or die ("ERROR: Cannot connect");

//$sql = "INSERT INTO facturas_xml (rfc, nombre_rs, calle) VALUES ('$rfc', '$desxml', '$calle')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO facturas_xml (rfc, nombre_rs, calle, no_exterior, no_interior, colonia, municipio, estado, pais, cp, nombre) VALUES ('$rfc', '$nombre_rs', '$calle', '$no_exterior', '$no_interior', '$colonia', '$municipio', '$estado', '$pais', '$cp', '$nombre_rs')";
mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die ("ERROR: " .mysqli_error($connection) . " (query was $sql)");

// close connection
mysqli_close($connection);

require 'view/carga.view.php';

?>
```

---

```html
<html>

<header>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
</header>
<body>
<h2>Carga de archivos </h2>
<?php if(strlen($msj)>0):?>
<div><?php echo $msj; ?></div>
<?php endif;?>
<form action="obtener.php" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo"></input>
    <input type="submit" name="subir" value="Subir archivo"></input>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/file_get_contents  your code makes no sense...

Comment: See [PHP Handling File Uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Comment: @MarcB in the previous code i have $xmlCont=file_get_contents('file.xml'); withtout the html works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, You want to read the contents of the currently uploaded file. If you just want to read the contents of the uploaded file, you can simply use

```
<?php
  $contents = file_get_contents($_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'];
 //$contents contains the content of the currently uploaded file.
?>
```

Comment: Yes, i want to read it from a load file, but how can i load the file and with other button read the xml and do all the rest of the code?